# Assign variables and display results

Tags: php

```
    <?php 
$somevariable = echo $anothervar;
?>
```

i get a T_ECHO unexpected error . what is the right way of accomplishing the above task?

I am extending this question a little bit :

```
<?php
    $num_posts = get_option($shortname.'_num_posts');
     $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => $num_posts,
            'post_type' => 'post'
                   );
?>
```

This is a bit of wordpress code . The *get_option* function doesn't echo the value , so i tried

```
<?php
    $num_posts = echo get_option($shortname.'_num_posts');
     $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => $num_posts,
            'post_type' => 'post'
                   );
?>
```

and i messed it . what is the right way to do it ?

Comment: What exactly is the above task? Do you want to print the value of `$anothervar` or assign it to `$somevariable`?

Comment: are you trying to assign the value of $anothervar to $somevariable?

Comment: @Jon yes i want to assign the value of $anothervar to $somevariable

Comment: what's the right way? **why not to just echo $num_posts**, dude?

Comment: I don't want to echo it , i want its value in that array.

Comment: that's amazing, dude. Go on, you've got talent ;)

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what you are trying to do. `echo` is a language construct, so returns nothing, so its return value cannot be assigned.

If you want to echo a value and assign it to another variable, it is best (most legible) to do it in two statements:

```
<?php

echo $anothervar;
$somevariable = $anothervar;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should just be

```
<?php $somevariable = $anothervar; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do? If you want print, the code is:

```
<?php 
$somevariable = $anothervar;
?>
```

If you want to assign the value of the another var, the code is:

```
<?php 
echo $anothervar;
$somevariable = $anothervar;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for you to catch any data from the function get_option you most return it from within the function itself:

```
<?php
function get_option($var){
    return $var; 
}

$num_posts = get_option($shortname.'_num_posts');

 //outputs what ever was returned from the function
 echo $num_posts;

?>
```

Comment: get_option is a inbuilt wordpress function .

Comment: Yeah, I know I was trying to show you the concept how you get a value out of a function in PHP. Check if this function is suppose to return any data, or maybe there is an error and the function return false which is nothing.